# In C#, is there a kind of a SortedList<double> that allows fast querying (with LINQ) for the nearest value?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, sortedlist

I am looking for a structure that holds a sorted set of double values. I want to query this set to find the closest value to a specified reference value.

I have looked at the `SortedList<double, double>`, and it does quite well for me. However, since I do not need explicit key/value pairs. this seems to be overkill to me, and i wonder if i could do faster.

Conditions:

- The structure is initialised only once, and does never change (no insert/deletes)
- The amount of values is in the range of 100k.
- The structure is queried often with new references, which must execute **fast**.
- For simplicity and speed, the set's value just below of the reference may be returned, not actually the nearest value
- I want to use LINQ for the query, if possible, for simplicity of code.
- I want to use no 3rd party code if possible. .NET 3.5 is available.
- Speed is more importand than memory footprint

I currently use the following code, where `SortedValues` is the aforementioned `SortedList`

```
    IEnumerable<double> nearest = from item in SortedValues.Keys
                                  where item <= suggestion
                                  select item;
    return nearest.ElementAt(nearest.Count() - 1);
```

**Can I do faster?**

Also I am not 100% percent sure, if this code is really safe. `IEnumerable`, the return type of my query is not by definition sorted anymore. However, a Unit test with a large test data base has shown that it is in practice, so this works for me. Have you hints regarding this aspect?

*P.S. I know that there are many similar questions, but none actually answers my specific needs. Especially there is this one [C# Data Structure Like Dictionary But Without A Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363773/c-data-structure-like-dictionary-but-without-a-value), but the questioner does just want to check the existence not find anything.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way you are doing it is incredibly slow as it must search from the beginning of the list each time giving O(n) performance.

A better way is to put the elements into a List and then [sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) the list. You say you don't need to change the contents once initialized, so sorting once is enough.

Then you can use [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839.aspx) to find elements or to find the insertion point of an element if it doesn't already exist in the list.

From the docs:

> Return Value
>
> The zero-based index of
>   item in the sorted `List<T>`,
>   if item is found; otherwise, a
>   negative number that is the bitwise
>   complement of the index of the next
>   element that is larger than item or,
>   if there is no larger element, the
>   bitwise complement of Count.

Once you have the insertion point, you need to check the elements on either side to see which is closest.

Comment: Depends on how often you want to find a Nearest-Item vs how often the list is refreshed.

Comment: See the question. The list will never have any inserts or removals.

Comment: Wow, talk about abusing return values.

Comment: Mark, ur da man! This executes roughly 200 times faster than my provided version.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be useful to you right now, but .Net 4 has a [SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28VS.100%29.aspx) class in the BCL.

Comment: How can you use a SortedSet to find the nearest element in the case where the exact element doesn't exist?

Comment: In the same manner he currently does. I wasn't addressing the performance aspect of the question, since you'd already answered. My answer was intended to point the OP to a non KVP data structure he might find useful.

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be more elegant as follows:
In case your items are not sorted:

```
double nearest = values.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Last(x => x.Key <= requestedValue);
```

In case your items are sorted, you may omit the OrderBy call...

Comment: This would be more elegant, though not faster as I asked for. -1 for not answering the question.